# AJAX POST - Working in IE, Chrome, Not Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript function that posts to a PHP page to assign session vars.

Here is the code for the update function:

```
function updateSession() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "update-session.php",
  data: $('#welcome').serialize() + '&ajax=true'
  });
}
```

When I run this function, I get an error on line '8630' for jQuery which is a line containing the following:

```
try {
  // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
  xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
} catch ( e ) {
  // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
  if ( callback ) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The POST is not going across a different domain and I have already tried using the full URL in the AJAX POST.

My request headers are below:

```
Accept  
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  
124
Content-Type    
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
X-Requested-With    
XMLHttpRequest
```

I've also tried using different versions of jQuery.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think I made some progress - I have the submit function doing form validation, then running the ajax and finally doing a window.location - if I replace the window.location with return false the POST works, but I still need to redirect the page after the submit button is pressed. Any ideas?

Comment: well add a success event and redirect when it is done...

Comment: That worked! ( I guess that and the combo of returning false in the submit function allowed the Ajax POST ) - thanks!